# How to switch an extension's language?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, translation

Unfortunately some Firefox extensions include rather bad/or incomplete translations into my locale (German), and I'd really prefer having them in English instead. However, I do not want to change my system language. I know I can replace the offending extension's `locale\de` path by the `en-US` one, but is there no other way to globally have all extensions in English while Firefox itself is allowed to remain German?

Comment: I would suspect this is a choice by the plugin - and the plugin could probably override any global setting :(

Comment: @Dave That would be highly unpleasant :/ It might at least be possible to create an extension that spoofs an English Firefox to all (or selected) extensions, or something similar to [QLS](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quick-locale-switcher/) for extensions...